# Can I read a device using PyUSB on MacBook Pro from USB-C converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, virtualenv, pyusb

Is it possible to read a device plugged into the USB-C converter using PyUSB? I have a sensor device plugged into a USB to micro USB cable which is plugged into the USB-C.

Comment: You will have to try it out. However, `libusb` supports USB-C and I can e.g. read all devices connected to my Belkin USB-C multimedia hub.

Comment: @hoefling I have `libusb` installed via `brew` and have a little script right now that only reads the ports of the USB-C and not what is plugged into it. I'm trying to access what's plugged into it obviously.

Comment: So your question is "how can I write a device driver"? Either get the device specs to see what commands you can send, or do reverse engineering yourself.

Comment: @hoefling So I tried a different USB device (mouse) and it was readable. I guess it's the way the sensor is plugged in. (USB to micro USB cable to Neonode sensor)